# Read in numbers from a text file

Tags: python, python-3.7

I'm trying to read in numbers from a text file that would look something like this:

```
file.txt:
5
2 3 4 2 3 6 8 4 5
```

Where the first line contains one number which represents an integer *k*. Following that are a variable number of integers split by spaces that I need to feed into an array as integers so I can do some arithmetic on them.

```
import sys

fileName = sys.argv[1]

with open(fileName) as f:
    k = [int(x) for x in next(f).split()] # read first line, this will be k
    print("Value for _k_")
    print(k)
    arrayInts = [] # array used for the numbers
    for line in f: # read rest of numbers
        arrayInts.append([int(x) for x in line.split()])
    print("The list of integers:")
    print(arrayInts)
```

Now the arrayInts prints out fine, but the type is "list", which I'm having trouble using for arithmetic. For some reason I'm having trouble converting it to an array of ints as well.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This line `arrayInts.append([int(x) for x in line.split()])` is creating a list with the integers in that line and then appends that list to the `arrayInts` list. Hence you get a list of lists. If you simply want all the ints in one list, you can do the following:

```
arrayInts = [] # array used for the numbers
for line in f: # read rest of numbers
    for x in line.split():
    arrayInts.append(int(x))
```

Comment: you can do as `arrayInts = [int(x) for x in line.split()]` instead of writing for loop.

Comment: That would reset the array every time and at the end we will only have the last line of numbers in the array.

Comment: ok. got it. I thought there are numbers on only line 2. No more lines. But yeah if there are more lines then it would not work.